# What do I need to legally use copyrighted music in my game?

Tags: copyright, music

I asked the singer of a song I am using, and he agreed to me using his music, provided I credit him. Do I need anything else, such as an agreement or signature?

Comment: We are no lawyers, but something written is always better than some loose agreement.

Comment: You might be using this music in Unity; but your question has nothing to do with Unity, itself, so I have removed the tag.

Comment: Could you find suitable music on a site like Jamendo, or even get the singer to publish there first? That could help protect you.

Comment: Is the singer the actual copyright holder of the piece?

Comment: Related with good FAQ's: https://sonymusiclicensing.com/ https://www.bmg-e-license.com/

Comment: Related blog post on Gamesutra: http://gamasutra.com/blogs/CatherineLevesque/20130314/188552/How_to_license_music_the_indie_way.php

Answer (score 41):

First and foremost, I am not a lawyer. You should *always* consult a lawyer in regards to legal questions - the legal system is often very fickle, and often changes dramatically from location to location.

---

### Can you legally use this music piece? It is impossible to tell.

You tell us you have permission from the *singer*. The first thing you need to find out is whether the singer actually holds *all* copyright reservations for the piece. The singer *performing* in the piece does not necessarily mean *anything*, in regards to copyright. Do your research. Find out who actually *wrote* the piece. Find out if it is a solo work, or a collaboration. Find out if the original writers actually *own* the copyright; under certain circumstances, the actual copyright could still belong to somebody entirely differant.

Do *not* assume that any one person retains all copyright on the simple basis that they are the one *performing* the piece. It is also worth considering that you could still be receiving the wrong information from the artist; perhaps they do not realise that the ten second sample they took from another song could impose *serious* copyright infringement. Perhaps they know very well, but would rather just say they hold all rights, to ensure further publicity.

### What should I do to legally acquire use of a song?

The only *effective* way to legally acquire the use of a song is to *consult a lawyer*. Preferably a copyright lawyer, as they will be more knowledgeable of the particular domain of law you are trying to follow. I say *effective*, because there is no *sure-fire* way to ensure legal process; at least, not in regards to ensuring you do not get sued. The potential copyright holder could still sue you after *all* assurances have been made. It is then up to the courts to decide whether you have legitimate ground; in the mean time, you could be up for very expensive legal fees.

#### On receiving confirmation for use

You also want to consider the form of your original "contract". How has the artist approved usage of their song? Via electric message? You would have to prove that you were actually talking to the artist; and *not* somebody else. It does not matter who that "somebody else" could be - a friend, a family member or somebody hacking in to the account - this assurance could easily be thrown out on the *chance* that it was not the original artist replying to your messages.

If this "contract" was verbal, you're in even more trouble. In many cases, a verbal contract is referred to as "non-binding". It is not that they have no *merit*, but it is often hard to prove that they actually said what you claim they said. It becomes a case of "he said, she said", which again, often offers no bearing in court.

#### On writing up a written contract

Do not bother signing a legal contract, yourself, without a lawyer. In some cases, a contract is null and void simply on the basis that the parties signed *without* a lawyer.

---

### TL;DR: If you want to legitimately use somebody else's song in your game, you should consult a lawyer. If you can not afford to consult a lawyer, you can not afford to defend your right to use the song, should any issues actually come about.

Comment: "It is also worth considering that you could still be receiving the wrong information from the artist; perhaps they do not realise that the ten second sample they took from another song could impose serious copyright infringement." If they plagiarized a song and lied about it and would ordinarily hold all other copyright then the one who got plagiarized would need to prove you were aware the piece was plagiarized. Ten seconds of ripped audio is not something you can sue *recipients* of the music over. By that reasoning they could sue any listeners for piracy of their music.

Comment: Note I'm not a lawyer but I know that there are some things to extreme to actually be used against you. The worst is they force you to change the audio and even then it would allow you to sue the so-called "original" creator.

Comment: @Typhon prefacing a legal pronouncement with "I am not a lawyer." seems to negate the point of the comment all together...

Comment: The only thing I would add to this answer is existing licenses, works in the public domain, and as another answer suggested an existing licensing agency.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake no it doesn't. It merely protects me from being sued for my statement being true in literally ever circumstance. My point was merely that you cannot be held at fault for someone else committing *plagiarism*.

Comment: @Typhon "literally ever" is clearly false, as at least one case the user of a sample was ordered to destroy all copies. [music sampling legal issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_issues_surrounding_music_sampling), and Vanilla Ice was forced to give up all earnings from his song to the owners of the song he sampled. [Review of the Legalities of Music Sampling](http://www.wipo.int/wipo_magazine/en/2009/06/article_0006.html).

Comment: @Typhon, also, you can be sued for *anything*. The legal battle that follows prooves if it is legitimate or not, and regardless, that can be very expensive.

Comment: @Gnemlock yes, but unless I misunderstood the commenter, they seemed to be arguing that there would be no hot water.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake, yes, that comment could be particularly dangerous, if acted on.

Comment: For those who are wondering if the user of a song can be sued over a sample within the song, even one legally obtained, see: [Apple sued over voice sample](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/thr-esq/apple-sued-use-jamie-xx-song-iphone-advertisement-968352).

Comment: I was saying there would be no hot water in the single extreme circumstance that an author plagiarizes literally 10 seconds within their 5-10 minute piece. Nobody in their right mind would say that you could ever feasibly be aware that the music was taken from some obscure source. I was *only* referring to that extreme case.

Comment: Also, there are things you cannot just randomly sue for without justification. Courts won't accept every bs lawsuit they see that won't pan out. If they can trivially reject something, they most likely will reject it before it reaches a judge and wastes everyone's time. By being sued I merely meant a lawsuit that logically have a win in favor of the person suing. I didn't realize I had to be that precise.

Comment: @Typhon, it helps to *always* be that precise. It doesn't matter how trivial you may think a case is, if the "other side" wish to pursue it, it is still going to cost you something to defend yourself. True, if the matter is *especially* trivial, this may just be a time cost; however, you would likely need a lawyer way before you start talking about going to *court*. In fact, if you do not have a lawyer present for the initial agreement, some jurisdictions would not consider the original agreement *binding*. Lawyers cost money.

Comment: Again, this is all based on circumstance, and location has a *giant* impact. What may hold true for one state or country, may not in another. Another reason why these matters call for a lawyer.

Comment: @Gnemlock true, but my main point was that people are unlikely to sue you for buying a liscence to use the music, since you would basically be someone getting duped by the theif. After all, it would be incredibly hard to detect that little stolen content without analysis or the original writer noticing it. That was my main point... that inevitably getting duped will occur and to not go to such an extreme that you basically avoid all music you dont personally create... since if you do get duped you likely won't be held responsible aside from being told to remove it.

Comment: "In some cases, a contract is null and void simply on the basis that it was not written by a lawyer"--this is absurd on its face.

Comment: @Gnemlock I'm willing to bet serious money that the contract was voided because it was defective somehow and not because "lawyers have to write contracts to be valid". Now hiring a lawyer is likely to help you avoid invalid contracts, but there's no Stamp Act requiring you to pay one.

Comment: @Gnemlock "In fact, if you do not have a lawyer present for the initial agreement, some jurisdictions would not consider the original agreement binding" - name one such jurisdiction.

Answer (score 16):

The singer is just a small part of a music track. It consists of:

- The vocals provided by the singer
- The text of the lyrics
- The composition of the melody
- The arrangement of the melody
- The performance of musicians playing the melody
- Individual audio samples used in the song
- The final audio mix of all these things together

All these creative inputs can be provided by different people and when any of these people feels that their copyrights are violated by you they might cause you trouble. So you need to make sure that you own the rights to **all** of this before you use a song in your game.

To make things simpler, most record labels secure the exclusive and redistributable rights to all these things before they publish a song, making it possible for them to relicense the whole song as a whole.

A common clause for art license contracts is that the licensor guarantees that they own all the copyrights and that they are liable in case that turns out to be wrong. You might want to ask a lawyer specialized in copyright law to draft the contract.

Answer (score 7):

In the 90s I worked for the largest computing magazine in Hungary and we had a cover CD, some 30 000 copies a month. We offered up and coming musicians to put their music there for free. This was insanely popular with our audience and the musicians both. A bit later the collective rights management agency in the country sued us and won because the law said you needed to pay them a fee per copy per minute. This is called a mechanical royalty. So even if the copyright holder grants you a license and very glad actually to spread their music you might not be in the clear. Definitely lawyer up.

Comment: +1 There are various rights associated with a piece of music: public performance, mechanical, etc, and the OP needs to also understand this.

Answer (score 5):

### Licensing from the authors

This can be complicated if a copyright collecting agency or a licensing agency in involved. If you deal directly with the authors, they can issue you a license.

If that license is exclusive, we want to make sure it is not fake, thus we want the license written and signed by the author or digital and digitally signed. The author may want to seek legal advice to do this.

---

Authors, because - as the other answers have stated - the audio recording involves diverse intellectual property, including the interpretation of the lyrics and melody, samples, audio composition, etc.

You have permission from the singer of the music you want, is the singer also the writer of the song? What about the people who play instruments? Did they use any samples from third party? In addition, somebody composed and edited the final recording, what about that intellectual property?

This can be further complicated. For example, if I want to record a song that written by another musician, I need to license that song, and the license I acquire may or may not allow me to license my recordings of it.

---

### Licensing from a licensing agency

You must find out if a licensing agency manages the particular work, in accordance to depending on local law.

In some places, the law states that authors needs an affiliation to a licensing agency appointed by the government in order to legally earn revenue form their work, this is not true worldwide. Furthermore, in some countries, the author needs to apply for a special permit to license their work outside of a licensing agency.

If there is a licensing agency managing the copyright of the work, that agency will define the procedure to follow to license the work, and how to pay any loyalties.

---

Licensing agencies should make it easy for authors to license their work and earn loyalties from them. They serve as intermediary between the licensee and the author, and often charge a fraction of the loyalties (although there are other business models and payment schemes for the authors, those are particular of the agency in question).

Consider, for example, a T.V. show that used music from a particular artist. Evidently, the T.V. producer has to acquire a license for that music. Furthermore, according to that license, reruns of the T.V. show may generate loyalties for the author. A licensing agency will keep track of that, and keep the revenue stream flowing... for a fee.

Comment: Sometimes licensing fails even if you try. You will see this when they change the theme song for a DVD release or similar.